# Nearby Places in Google Place sdk displays places without Addresses

Tags: android, google-places-api

We are using Google Service location 11.6.0

We started to notice that If we select Current Location or Search Places, We get all address parameters.

But the "Nearby Places" List displays the nearby places without address. On selection of this places we don't see Address parameters only long&lat

Comment: Please add the codes that does what you just explained to make it clearer.